# Is it OK to wash/submerge the Pi in water after Soldering

Tags: hardware

I'm using a water soluble flux when soldering headers to the Raspberry PI, apparently the flux should be washed off with water!

Is that likely to cause problems?

**Update:** I wouldn't solder whilst powered on, it stands to reason I wouldn't wash it with water whilst powered on.

Comment: This is not what you have asked for, but asking about water, one may interested in the [question about  waterproof cases](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/206/building-a-waterproof-case)

Comment: Mods tag is for hw modification? Safety tag, what's that got to do with it?

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't be a problem, provided precautions are taken.

Make sure it is completely disconnected from everything, use de-ionised water as it is far less conductive then usual tap water, and allow it to dry somewhere warm for at least a week to be absolutely sure. While drying, pack it with silica gel or rice which will help to absorb moisture as it evaporates. The de-ionised water is more an extra precaution in case any moisture does manage to remain after this drying process.

This will invalidate the warranty and still does not guarantee success (disclaimer: don't blame me if it goes wrong) but it should significantly reduce the risk.

Comment: I've tried to keep water away from the cpu, the thought of water getting between the ram and the cpu does concern me a bit :-$

Comment: I think if you remove the first sentence this answer would be more acceptable. Electricity and water doesn't mix but the vast majority of electronics products are washed with water after the soldering process, my question is specific to the RPi. Maybe I should update the question a bit.

Comment: @DogEars I've updated this answer to better relate to your edited question.

Comment: I'm not sure de-ionised water is used because if it's insulative properties but because of it's a more aggressive solvent and secondly it is less likely to leave mineral deposits, as soon as it starts dissolving away deposits it ceases to be de-ionized anyway!

Comment: That may be why others may choose to use it and so they are welcome to update this answer or post their own (as are you), but personally my reason for using it would be to reduce risk of conduction.

Answer (score 4):

Please do not submerge or wash your Pi with water. This is likely to both destroy you Pi and void your warranty. I would suggest changing the flux you are using, or if you have already done so leave the residue assuming it is non conductive. Is this flux even designed for electronics?

In general water and electronics do not go well together.

Comment: Why should it cause problems as long as it drys completely?

Comment: The flux is corrosive (Kester 2331-zx)

Comment: @Scolytus How can you be sure it dries completely?

Comment: @DogEars as the flux is corrosive and you have already used it on your Pi this question may be moot and you don't really have a choice.

Comment: @Scolytus It's more the effect that the water will have on the metal, and the residue it may leave behind that are the concern.

Comment: @Jivings - we're in a soft water area, the minerals contained in the water aren't surely as bad as not removing the flux? I'm confused why these answers are getting up-voted when there's no components on the RPi that would cause a problem if immersed in water!

Comment: Please don't post uninformed speculation.  Clean water wash is routine in electronics manufacturing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - if you can provide a correct answer you'll get my vote.